# Change format of sheets name for VLOOKUP formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fetch Net Close Qty from each sheets into a new sheet, before this I've been using 01-12 as sheets name that representing Jan-Dec. I want to change the sheet name become Jan-Dec instead of 01-12. How do I change the format? Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
Sub NCQ()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim j As Byte

    j = 1

'// 3(space between columns) x 12(sheets) x 2(lookup columns in each sheet)
For i = 3 To (3 * 12) Step 2
    With Sheets("Net Close Qty")
        With .Cells(1, i).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A1,'" & Format$(j, "00") & "'!$A$1:$T$155," & IIf(i Mod 6 = 3, 3, 3) & ",FALSE)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
    j = j + 1
Next

'Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Include:

```
dts = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec"
ary = Split(dts, ",")
```

near the top and then use:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A1,'" & ary(j - 1) & "'!$A$1:$T$155," & IIf(i Mod 6 = 3, 3, 3) & ",FALSE)"
```

**EDIT#1:**

This has not been tested, but can be used as a starting point:

```
Sub NCQ()
    Dim lastRow As Long, dts As String
    Dim j As Long, i As Long

    dts = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec"
    ary = Split(dts, ",")
    j = 1
    For i = 3 To 36 Step 2
        With Sheets("Net Close Qty")
            With .Cells(1, i).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
                .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A1,'" & ary(j - 1) & "'!$A$1:$T$155," & IIf(i Mod 6 = 3, 3, 3) & ",FALSE)"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, where do I put the first 2 code? because it seems to have run-time error '9'

Comment: @phelia91  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: thanks a lot, its working perfectly but then there an error "run-time error 9 : Subscript out of range" for this line  .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A1,'" & ary(j - 1) & "'!$A$1:$T$155," & IIf(i Mod 6 = 3, 3, 3) & ",FALSE)". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @phelia91 you are iterating 18 times on a 12 object long array.  Either make your array longer by another 6 months or change the step to 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hi, I'm still learning. Thanks for helping and the problem solved!